# eBay listing generator - revised

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, ebay

I posted my first attempt at this [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/55185/javascript-ebay-listing-generator/55576?noredirect=1#comment98071_55576). It's an app that generates both a preview of an interactive eBay listing, as well as the raw code which the user can copy and paste into their listing.

I received some friendly suggestions about separating all the HTML/CSS/JS markup which needs to be included in the preview and in the raw code container into separate files which would be loaded and rendered into a single widget.

First, my index.html file contains the following markup which is populated via JS:

```
<!-- The output container contains raw code for copying/pasting -->
<div id="output">
    <div class="style"></div>
    <div class="html"></div>
    <div class="script"></div>
</div>

<!-- The preview container contains the same code, but rendered -->
<div id="preview">
    <style id="listGenStyle"></style>
    <div id="listGenHTML"></div>
    <script id="listGenScript"></script>
</div>
```

The contents of `listGen.css` which goes in both `$('#output .style')` as plain text and $('#preview #listGenStyle')` as HTML is simple, run-of-the-mill CSS. Probably not much use posting it here.

Here is `listGen.html`, which goes in `$('#output .html')` as text, and in `$('#preview #listGenHTML')` as HTML:

```
<table id="mblParentContainer"> 
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div class="mblWrpr"> 
                    <!-- I'm omitting the rest of the markup for the sake of saving space. But here would be the header, nav, mobile nav, slideshow, listing title, content boxes, footer --> 
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Here is the contents of listGen.js which goes in both `$('#output .script')` as plain text as well as `$('#preview #listGenSCript')` as HTML (NOTE - `iq` is a global window object I created that returns a set of commonly used methods to make writing behaviors easier; I'm leaving it out because I imagine it's pretty obvious what these functions are accomplishing):

```
    iq.show(iq.sel("#mblSlide img:first-child"));
    iq.show(iq.sel(".mblHide.one"));
    iq.sel(".mblNav ul li:first-child").style.background = "#000"; 
    iq.sel(".mblNav ul li:first-child .triangle").style.display = "block"; 
    iq.sel(".mblNav ul li:first-child").style.borderBottom = "2px solid #66e2e3"; 
    iq.sel(".mblNav ul li:first-child a").style.color = "#66e2e3"; 
    iq.sel(".mblNav ul li:first-child a").style.textTransform = "uppercase";
    iq.click("a", function(){
        if (iq.hasClass(iq.sel("#mblMobile"), "open") && this.parentNode.parentNode.getAttribute("class") === "mblMM") {
            iq.fadeOut(100, iq.sel(".mblFadeWrapper")); 
            iq.fadeOut(100, iq.sel("#mblMobile"));
            iq.removeClass(iq.sel("#mblMobile"), "open");
        } else if (!iq.hasClass(iq.sel("#mblMobile"), "open") && this.parentNode.parentNode.getAttribute("class") === "mblMM") {
            iq.fadeIn(100, iq.sel("#mblMobile")); 
            iq.fadeIn(100, iq.sel(".mblFadeWrapper"));
            iq.addClass(iq.sel("#mblMobile"), "open");
        }
        var cls = iq.map("a", "class");  
        for (var i = 0; i < cls.length; i++) {
            if (this.getAttribute("class") === cls[i]) { 
                iq.show(iq.sel(".mblHide." + cls[i]));
                iq.scrollWindow(".mblHide." + cls[i]);
                iq.sel("a."+cls[i]).style.color = "#66e2e3"; 
                iq.sel("a."+cls[i]).style.textTransform = "uppercase"; 
                iq.sel("a."+cls[i]).parentNode.style.background = "#000"; 
                iq.sel("a."+cls[i]).parentNode.style.borderBottom = "2px solid #66e2e3";  
                iq.sel("a."+cls[i]).parentNode.children[1].style.display = "block";
                var toHide = iq.selAll(".mblHide:not(." + cls[i] + ")");
                var a = iq.selAll(".mblMainNav a:not(."+cls[i]+")");
                for (var j = 0; j < toHide.length; j++) {
                    iq.hide(toHide[j]);
                    for (var k = 0; k < a.length; k++) {
                        a[k].style.color = ""; 
                        a[k].style.textTransform = ""; 
                        a[k].parentNode.style.background = ""; 
                        a[k].parentNode.style.borderBottom = "";  
                        a[k].parentNode.children[1].style.display = "";
                    } 
                } 
            } 
        } 
    });
    iq.click(".menu-trigger", function(){
        iq.addOrRemoveClass(iq.sel("#mblMobile"), "open");
        if (iq.hasClass(iq.sel("#mblMobile"), "open")) {
            iq.fadeIn(100, iq.sel(".mblFadeWrapper")); 
            iq.fadeIn(100, iq.sel("#mblMobile")); 
        } else {
            iq.fadeOut(100, iq.sel("#mblMobile")); 
            iq.fadeOut(100, iq.sel(".mblFadeWrapper"));
        } 
    });
    iq.click("#mblThumbs img", function(){ 
        var dn = iq.map("img", "data-name"); 
        for (var i = 0; i < dn.length; i++) { 
            if (this.getAttribute('data-name') === dn[i]) { 
                var outs = iq.selAll('#mblSlide img:not([data-name="' + dn[i] + '"])'); 
                for (var j = 0; j < outs.length; j++) { 
                    iq.fadeOut(100, outs[j]); 
                } 
                iq.fadeIn(200, iq.sel('#mblSlide img[data-name="' + dn[i] + '"]')); 
            } 
        } 
    });
    var num = iq.sel(".mblHOne").nextElementSibling.innerHTML.replace(/.10/g, "");
    var stars = iq.selAll(".star"); 
    var arr = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < stars.length; i++) {
        arr.push(stars[i]);
    }
    arr.splice(0, num);
    for (var j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) { 
        arr[j].style.color = "black";
    }
    var thumbs = iq.selAll("#mblThumbs img");
    for (var k = 0; k < thumbs.length; k++) {
        if (thumbs[k].getAttribute("src") === "") { 
            thumbs[k].remove(); 
        }
    }
    var logo = iq.sel(".mblHdr img");
    if (logo.getAttribute("src") === "undefined") { 
        iq.hide(logo);
    } else {
        iq.show(logo);
    }
    iq.click(".back-to-top", function(){ 
        iq.scrollWindow(".mblWrpr"); 
    });
```

And finally, my script.js file, which does the work of grabbing all of the above files, and populating the HTML elements and their attributes where needed:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    // We need the HTML template right away so we populate it
    // with variables declared in this script.
    // We'll grab the external CSS and JS after the HTML
    // template is fully populated.
    $('#listGenHTML').load('listGen.html');
//***********************************************************************************
//                                         OUTPUT GENERATION FUNCTIONS
//***********************************************************************************

    // On form submit, populate code output container and preview container
    $('#form1').on('submit', function(e) {

        e.preventDefault();

        // Set the src attribute for the logo image if it exists
        var logoSrc = $('#company-logo .preview img').attr('src');
        if (logoSrc) {
            logoSrc = logoSrc.replace(/\/thumbnail/g, '');
        }
        $('.mblHdr img').attr('src', logoSrc);

        // Grab values of menu item inputs and use them to populate 
        // the main nav and mobile nav, as well as the corresponding description header
        var menu = [];
        $('.menuItems input').each(function(){
            menu.push($(this).val());
        });

        for (var h = 0; h < menu.length; h++) {
            $('.mblMainNav li').eq(h).find('a').text(menu[h]);
            $('.mblMM li').eq(h).find('a').text(menu[h]);
            $('.mblDescHdr').eq(h).text(menu[h]);
        }


        // Grab the href and src attributes for uploaded images and their links
        // and use them to populate the slideshow
        var fullSizeSrc = [];
        var thumbSrc = [];
        var total = $('#slide-upload tr').length;
        for (var i =1; i <= total; i++){
            var fss = $('#slide-upload tr:nth-child('+i+') td:first a').attr('href');
            var ts = fss.replace(/\/thumbnail/g, '');
            fullSizeSrc.push(fss);
            thumbSrc.push(ts);
        }

        for (var j = 0; j < fullSizeSrc.length; j++) {
            $('#mblSlide a').eq(j).attr('href', fullSizeSrc[j]);
            $('#mblSlide a').eq(j).find('img').attr('src', fullSizeSrc[j]);
        }

        for (var k = 0; k < thumbSrc.length; k++) {
            $('#mblThumbs img').eq(k).attr('src', thumbSrc[k]);
        }

        // Get the values entered in the item description textareas
        // and populate the description boxes
        var itemDesc = [];
        $('.desc-boxes textarea').each(function(){
            itemDesc.push($(this).val());
        });

        for (var l = 0; l < itemDesc.length; l++) {
            $('.mblParaDesc').eq(l).text(itemDesc[l]);
        }

        // Get the value of the Item Title input field and populate the item title header
        var itemTitle = $('.itemTitle').val();
        $('.mblHOne').text(itemTitle);

        // Get the value of the Item Rating input field and populate the item rating
        var itemRating = $('.itemRating').val();
        $('.rating').text(itemRating+'/10');

        // Get the script and insert as HTML into the proper script tag in #preview
        $('#listGenScript').load('listGen.js');

       // Get the stylesheet and insert as CSS into the proper style tag in #preview
        $('#listGenStyle').load('listGen.css', function(){
            // Populate code container with raw code
            $('#output .style').text('<style>' + $('#listGenStyle').html() + '</style>');
            $('#output .html').text($('#listGenHTML').html());
            $('#output .script').text('<script>' + $('#listGenScript').html() + '</script>');

            // Now we can show the preview container and UI buttons
            $('#preview').fadeIn();
            $('.continue-editing, .get-code, #form-clear').fadeIn();
        });
    });

    // Close the preview but keep all the input values and storage
    $('.continue-editing').click(function(){
        $('.continue-editing, .get-code, #form-clear').fadeOut();
        $('#output').fadeOut().empty();
        $('#preview').fadeOut();

    });

    // Same as above, but clear form and storage
    $('#form-clear').click(function(){
        document.forms.form1.reset();
        $('button[data-type="DELETE"]').each(function(){
            $(this).click();
        });
        $('#output').fadeOut().empty();
        $('#preview').fadeOut().empty();
        $('.continue-editing, .get-code, #form-clear').fadeOut();
        window.location.reload();
    });

    // View the code block output
    $('.get-code').click(function(){
        $('#output').toggle();
    });
});
```

For the most part all of this behaves as expected. I do have some specific issues, but I think SO might be the better platform for addressing those. Here I'm most interested in critiques of the code. How can I improve it/make it more efficient/make it easier to read or maintain?

Comment: It looks already a million times better, way to go!

Comment: @konijn: Thanks for the kind remark. I guess if you had a critique, you'd have mentioned it, but in case you do and you didn't mention it, please feel free. I'm pretty new at this, and I'm very eager for suggestions from experienced devs.

Comment: First, take a look at MVC principles! Favor `doThis();` over `//the following code does this` anti-pattern. Comments should almost never be necessary to understand the code. Break your code in multiple meaningfully named and manageable functions (small). Also name your variables carefully. Do not query the DOM over and over (e.g. do not repeat `$('#mblSlide a').eq(j)` instead cache the result `var $someEl = $('#mblSlide a').eq(j)` then reuse `$someEl`. Avoid inline styles when possible and consider using a templating language to generate your DOM structure.